# Convert Points into Lines and adding Average Z value for line attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, points-to-line

At the moment I am working with a lot of Point data. The Point Data has  X Y and Z Columns. I would like to convert this into line feature

Because there are multiply points in the line feature I would like to simplify the amount of vertices with in the line feature. 
So if a Potential Line had 26 Points I would make a step of 4 points per line feature taking an average of the Z values

See the image below of the point input and the desired output

I have looked at the points to line tool

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm

But I cannot see a way of averaging out the interval.

It is possible for me to work to work out averages in another text input in python.

I was wondering if anyone had some ideas on the best method to use to get the desired output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After Point To Line I would be thinking about [Linear Referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm) and linear events.

> Linear referencing is the method of storing geographic locations by
>   using relative positions along a measured linear feature. Distance
>   measures are used to locate events along the line

Once you have determined an algorithm for the categories symbolized in the right hand map, I would expect that Python/ArcPy would be needed to perform the averaging.